# django - Import Error: No module named: 'dashboard'

Tags: python, django, python-3.4

I am trying to roll my own dash board in django 1.9 using python 3.4. Within the main project app urls.py file I am trying to include the urls.py file from my new dashboard app.

### Directory Structure

```
venv/
pic/
    docs/
        (developer notes, deployment notes, etc)
    pic/
        __init__.py
        manage.py
        test.py
        apps/
            __init__.py
            dasboard/
                migrations/
                static/
                __init__.py
                admin.py
                apps.py
                models.py
                test.py
                urls.py
                views.py
            core/
                (other stuff unrelated to issue)
        pic/
            media/
            settings/
            static/
            __init__.py
            urls.py
            wsgi.py
```

### Related Files

#### pic/pic/pic/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^dashboard/', include('dashboard.urls')),
]
```

#### pic/pic/apps/dashboard/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from pic.apps.dashboard import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

#### pic/pic/apps/dashboard/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your dashboard views here.

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the dashboard index.")
```

#### pic/pic/pic/settings/base.py (selected relevant pieces)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'apps.core',
    'apps.dashboard',
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'pic.urls'
```

#### Error received accessing /dashboard/

```
ImportError at /dashboard/

No module named 'dashboard'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://dev.pic.com/dashboard/
Django Version:     1.9.6
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

No module named 'dashboard'

Exception Location:     /home/<user>/Repositories/Websites/pic/venv/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py in import_module, line 109
Python Executable:  /home/<user>/Repositories/Websites/pic/venv/bin/uwsgi
Python Version:     3.4.3
Python Path:    

['.',
 '',
 '/home/<user>/Repositories/Websites/pic/venv/lib/python3.4',
 '/home/<user>/Repositories/Websites/pic/venv/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/<user>/Repositories/Websites/pic/venv/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/<user>/Repositories/Websites/pic/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages']

Server time:    Sun, 26 Jun 2016 14:49:07 -0700
```

### Notes

127.0.0.1/admin/ works and loads the admin login properly.  I know that is all fine.
When attempting to access 127.0.0.1/dashboard/ I receive the error mentioned above.

When using the django shell  I can do `from apps import dashboard` successfully. `dashboard.models` returns the proper output, but `dashboard.urls` throws an `Attribute Error: 'module' object has no attribute 'urls'.  Not sure if that extra bit of information is useful, but I thought it was odd behavior. Discovered it while trying to debug this issue.

#### Background

I am familiar with older versions of django as I have been maintaining a 1.7 project for approx 5+ months.  My python experience is not substantial but I currently make a living doing so.  I am still learning things about django and python frequently though.

Thank you for taking the time to review my problem. I was hoping not to have to post here, but after 4 hours I have made no progress. I hope with your help I can figure this one out!

Comment: Have you tried `url(r'^dashboard/', include('apps.dashboard.urls')),`?

Comment: Your `apps` directory appears to be missing an `__init__.py` file.

Comment: @alecxe I did try that.  Unfortunately the issue persisted. I do get a new error stating that the module `pic.apps` can not be found instead of `dashboard`.

Comment: @Evert good eye, but it was only my digram that was incorrect I did have the file in my project.

Comment: surely a directory structure that goes pic/pic/pic is going to lead to never ending confusion. You will have to struggle with issues like this on a daily basis

Comment: @e4c5 quite possibly so.  An error involving 'pic' would then make you ask which 'pic'.  I'll have to refactor the naming and attempt debugging again. Thank you.

Comment: "the module `pic.apps` can not be found". `pic.apps` requires PYTHONPATH/sys.path to be one directory level *above* `manage.py` (I'm assuming this is using the dev-server). The path listing at the bottom of your error display shows neither the full path to the relevant directory (which seems to be `'/home/<user>/Repositories/Websites/pic`), nor the relative directory (which would be `..pic.apps`. Either change your import, or consider moving `manage.py` one directory up. (Or adjust your PYTHONPATH, but that feels like a last resort).

Comment: [continued from previous comment] Moving `manage.py` one dir up seems to be the logical option, since if you would ever install the project as a Python package in site-packages, `pic` would be the package, not `apps`. And you don't want to include `manage.py` in the package; it isn't a package. That way your import (`pic.apps.dashboard`) also makes sense.